# can I click one button and use the action of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two buttons, and I want to apply one action to another. For example.

```
<form>

<input type="submit" />
</form>

<input type="submit" />
```

I want to make the second button submit the form, despite being outside of the form.

Comment: confused by the downvote here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make them of type button, and give your form an id.

Markup:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <---STUFF---->
<input type='button' id='otherButton'>
</form>

<input type='button' id='someButton'>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() { $('#myForm').submit(); });
```

Comment: please don't educate people in using W3 Validation failure code teach them to use <button> when outside of a form

Comment: barfoon is, quite correctly, not modifying the OP's code more than necessary to illustrate their suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':input:last').click(function()
{
   $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// enable form submit on the second <input>
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
      $('form').submit();
});

// disable the inner <input>
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function(){
      return false;
});
```

Something like this should do your trick.

Comment: Again this will only work if there using Invalid HTML code <input tag must be contained in a Form tag and your code just wont work if there is more than 1 invalid input not in a form

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second button to do everything the first can do (not just submit), you can try something like this:

html

```
<form>
<input id="insideButton" type="submit" />
</form>

<input id="outsideButton" type="submit" />
```

<s>js</s>**JQUERY**

```
$("#outsideButton").click(function() {
    $("#insideButton").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score -3):

you can using jQuery $("#test").click() if you have jQuery instead of the document... stuff below or the way below will work without jQuery

```
<form name="testForm1">
<input type="submit" id="test" />
</form>
<!-- use this when not in a form: -->
<button onclick="button1_click();" id="button1"></button>
```

In your head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function button1_click(){
  document.forms.testForm1.submit();
}
</script>
```

Changed for the users that put performance under clean code

Comment: Woooo ppls please remove downVotes i forgot to click the code thing so the HTMl was stripped updated and dont be so fast to downvote when i only just posted think it could have been a basic error of the code highlighter not working, and @Tudorizer thanks but please look at the code i ment to post not what was bug posted by SO

Comment: Perhaps people simply don't like you mixing javascript with mark up?

Comment: The only way to do this is to use jQuery or such and the fact that people are so god damn reliant on jQuery now sickens me that all of the power of the DOM and EMCAScript that hundreds of people have put there lives into building gets disregarded for library that uses it yes its good but its not the be all and end all of javascript

Comment: jQuery normalizes the implementation-differences between different browsers. Try writing code that works the same in all modern browsers, without jQuery. You can do it, but it will be a lot more work. Finally the problem with your solution is also that it doesn't follow "Unobtrusive Javascript". It is better to bind event handler programmatically than through markup.